# google maps api geolocation doesn't update on timeout

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know this is probably not the most performant code possible, but if anyone can help I'd really appreciate that.
I'm working on a web-application that's supposed to locate the user's position with the google maps api. For this I created an UI control that starts the tracking of the user's current position and starts a timeout function that should update the position of the user. Everything works fine, but I testet the app when moving around and the geolocation doesn't change with the timeout, it always just shows the position of the first loop. I have to click on the UI control again to update the position.

These are the functions I adapted from the Google developer sites:

The function to detect the position:

```
    //locate the user via GPS by checking geopositioning
function locateUser(geoLoc) {   
  var geoSuccess = function(position, map) {
    startPos = position;
    userLat = startPos.coords.latitude;
    userLon = startPos.coords.longitude;
    geoLoc = {lat : userLat ,lng : userLon};

  };
  var geoError = function(error, map) {
    geoLoc = null; 
    //console.log('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
    // error.code can be:
    //   0: unknown error
    //   1: permission denied
    //   2: position unavailable (error response from location provider)
    //   3: timed out
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);

};    

locateUser(geoLoc);
```

I'm using the variable "geoLoc" to get latitude and longitude within the map api.

This is the function that is called by a click on the UI-control and that starts the timeout:

```
//set the marker for the current position to the geolocation, when geolocation is possible
function setUserPosition(map, geoLoc, controlUI) {
    //get the geolocation
    locateUser(geoLoc);

    //check if the position marker for the user position is already attached
    if (positionSet == false) {
    //if the position marker is not attached (first time user hits the UI control), generate and attach it nad notify the user that it's position is tracked

       positionSet = true;  

        var userpos = {
        url: "https://myhost.com/mygraphic.png", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45,45), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(23,23) // anchor
        };

        positionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: geoLoc,
        map: map,
        zIndex: 100,
        icon: userpos  
      }); 

    }

//Check if geolocation is possible.
//If geolocation is not possible, hide the location marker and change the UI control's state back to default, but try again in three seconds.
    if(geoLoc == null) {
      controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#4485F8';
      controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://myhost.com/oldbackgroundimage.png')";
      moveControl = false;
    } else {

//If geolocation is possible, make the position marker visible, set it to the located position and cahnge the UI's state to "active".
        posMark = positionMarker;

        posMark.setPosition(geoLoc); 

      controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#eeeef4';
      controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://myhost.com/newbackgroundimage.png')";
      moveControl = true; 

    } 

   map.panTo(geoLoc); 

//check if the user hit the button to start the positiontracking and loop the function if so    
   if(moveControl == true) {
    timeoutControl = setTimeout(function(){setUserPosition(map, geoLoc, controlUI)}, 3000);
   } else if(moveControl == false) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutControl);  
   }

}
```

And this is the function for the UI-control within the init-map function:

```
controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {

      //check if the user tapped the UI to locate the current position 
      if(moveControl == false) {
      moveControl = true;
      locateUser();

      //if geolocation is not possible, open an alert to notify the user      
      if(geoLoc == null) {
        alert("No geolocation :(");
      } else {
      //if geolocation is possible, set the UI control to the "active" state and start the interval to locate the user permanently (every three seconds)      
      controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#eeeef4';
      controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://myhost.com/newbackgroundimage.png')";
      setUserPosition(map, geoLoc, controlUI);  
      //Show the Position marker    
      posMark.setMap(map);

      }
      //if the user has tapped the UI control and is in "location-mode" this tap stops the location mode and sets everything back into default state
      } else if(moveControl == true) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutControl);
      moveControl = false;
      controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#4485F8';
      controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://myhost.com/oldbackgroundimage.png')"; 
      //Hide the Position marker    
      posMark.setMap(null);
      }     
  });
```

I ran the script with an alert to display geoLoc within the geoSucess function of the locateUser function and it gets executed every time the timeout runs over the code and always fires geoLoc with data, but always only the position the user had when he first clicked the UI control.

Can anybody help and does know why the position is not updated within the timeout or maybe know how it would be updated?

Thanks a lot & kind regards,
Philipp

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: So this is the function that gets the geolocation:                                                      
  "var geoSuccess = function(position, map) {
    startPos = position;
    userLat = startPos.coords.latitude;
    userLon = startPos.coords.longitude;
    geoLoc = {lat : userLat ,lng : userLon};

  };"
 and geoSuccess is called in a Timout but always delivers the same coordinates (the ones when first called), even when the user changes its position. When geoSuccess is called by a click event, it delivers new coordinates.